# Interfacing with iterators?

Tags: interface, iterator, containers

Given a class that have one or more container(s), is it a good practice to interface with iterators rather than the container(s)? (e.g. for clients that wish to browse through a container)

An iterator would somehow hide the implementation of the container(s), so for my part I think it is a good practice.

But I might not be aware of the consequences of providing iterators as interface techniques (if any) that other fellow programmers/designers encountered.

What is your opinions on this?